# Using UIPanGestureRecognizer to scroll smoothly like UITableView or UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using UIPanGestureRecognizer to slide/scroll a UIView. The following code works well and I am able to slide/scroll the panView. My question is when I end the gesture I should make the panView(UIView) scroll smoothly smiler like UITableView or UIScrollView scroll. So please help me out what should I code in UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded state. Please refer the below code. Thanks in advance!!

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollpanView:)];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [panView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

-(void)scrollpanView:(id)sender{
UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;
CGPoint translatedPoint = [gesture locationInView:[panView superview]].x;
if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    panXAxis = [gesture locationInView:[panView superview]].x;

translatedPoint = CGPointMake(panXAxis+translatedPoint.x, 50);
     [panView setCenter:translatedPoint];
}

if ( UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
translatedPoint = CGPointMake(panXAxis+translatedPoint.x, 50);
[panView setCenter:translatedPoint];
}


if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:[panView superview]]
// How should I scroll smoothly using the 'velocity' value
    }

}
```

Comment: `velocityInView:` returns the `CGPoint` not `float`

Comment: Thanks!! I will Change..

Comment: You have to scroll in `X` or `Y`

Comment: @PrashanthRajagopalan:
Did you achieve the scrolling like tableview with your pan gesture ?
Can you help me??